# How to compute the homology $R$-module of $\Bbb{Z}/8 \xrightarrow{4x} \Bbb{Z}/8 \xrightarrow{4x} \Bbb{Z}/8$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, modules, homological-algebra

Let $d_n(x) = 4x : \Bbb{Z}/8 \to \Bbb{Z}/8$ be the differential and let $C_n = \Bbb{Z}/8$ be the $n$th $R$-module in the chain complex.  Then $Z_n \equiv \ker d_n = \{\{0,2,4,6\} + \Bbb{Z}/8\}$ as a submodule of $\Bbb{Z}/8$ and $B_n \equiv \text{im } d_{n+1} = \{\{0,4\} + \Bbb{Z}/8\}$ so that the $n$th homology module of $C_.$ is $H_n = Z_n / B_n$ but how do I fully show that this is $\approx\Bbb{Z}/2$?

I know that $Z_n \approx \Bbb{Z}/4$ and $B_n \approx \Bbb{Z}/2$ but it seems like I should take the quotient by value and not by isomorphic value.

So:
$$ 
\bar{0} + B_n = B_n \\
\bar{2} + B_n = \{2, 6\} + B_n = ? \\
$$

which doesn't seem right to me.  How do I do this problem?  It's from Weibel, first page.

Comment: Are you asking why a group of order $2$ must be cyclic?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The exercise says to "compute the homology module".  How would I do that in general for $\Bbb{Z}$-modules?  But in particular for this example.

Comment: Just as you've done it: the homology is the quotient of $Z_n$ by the subgroup $B_n$. A cyclic group of order 4 factored by its subgroup of order 2.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  So I just say that it definitely has to be $\Bbb{Z}/2$ since 4/2 = 2 is the only solution divisibility-wise?

Comment: The quotient of a group of order 4 by one of order 2 must have order 2 surely?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown k, I see now.  Thank you!

Comment: You can tighten this up using the First Isomorphism Theorem: Construct a surjective map $Z_n \mapsto \mathbb{Z}/2$, observe that its kernel coincides precisely with $B_n$, and conclude that $Z_n/B_n \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 1$, $\ker(d_n)=\langle 2 \rangle$ which has order $4$, and $\mathrm{im}(d_n) = \langle 4 \rangle$ which has order $2$.

For $n=0$, $$H_n(C) = \ker(d_0)/\mathrm{im}(d_1)=(\mathbb Z/8)/\langle 4 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z/4.$$

For $n \ge 1$,
$$H_n(C) = \ker(d_n)/\mathrm{im}(d_{n+1})=\langle 2 \rangle / \langle 4 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z/2.$$